# How can I set colorcolumn=6 only for fortran files in vim?

Tags: vim

Background:

In the old Fortran style, the 6th column is for continuation and 72 is for the last column.  I currently have `set colorcolumn=6` in my vimrc file. But it also makes other files such as python or text files with the 6th column highlighted.

How can I:

```
 if filetype = 'fortran'
     set colorcolumn =6, 72
```

ie highlight both the 6th and 72nd columns if the filetype is fortran

Comment: fwiw, romainl has a nice answer regarding the high level approach to changing default filetype settings here, https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-can-i-change-the-default-indentation-based-on-filetype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autocmd FileType fortran set colorcolumn=6,72`

`autocmd FileType <file type>` will run the given commands when the file type is set / you open a file of the given type.

Comment: Is there a way to do the inverse, i.e. do something for everything except for Python files?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I suspect you already have your answer. But my recommendation for others would be to do something like `set cc=6,72` by default in your vimrc and then use `autocmd FileType python set cc=81` (or whatever you want different) to overwrite the default.